# What does the term "turnkey" means or refer to in the Engineering/Manufacturing environment?

Tags: pcb

I keep hearing this expression thrown around when talking about or to PCB fab houses. Can someone tell me what it means, or refer to ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: @Leon: Getting the things you designed built is a important part of electrical engineering.  Even if you are at a large company and don't interface with manufacturers personally, it is still important to understand the process.

Comment: I have actually laid out a design and as part of the process of sourcing pcb fab houses, i'm getting acquainted with some terms that i'm not familiar with. I don't know how that makes it off topic.

Comment: Argh. If I'd known you were going to accept the first answer you get after only 30 minutes, I wouldn't have bothered to write a detailed answer.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Please, always write detailed answer because your answers are great.

Comment: @Kaz: But how exactly that general English term is applied within the context of electrical engineering *is* on topic here.  This is a good question.  I often vote to close poorly worded, off topic, or badly written questions, but this one is none of those things.  Lighten up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Turnkey" means that you only provide documentation to someone else to build something.  They then source all the parts, get other parts modified or made, etc.  Basically you send them specs and money and they send you fully built units.

Note that this doesn't really apply to PCB fabrication.  Or more accurately, PCB fabrication is basically always turnkey anyway, so that term is not used in that context.  You don't provide copper sulfate, laminated FR4, or etching solution to the PCB house.  You provide only Gerber files (the documentation), and they do and buy whatever is necessary to make the complete finished boards.

What you are probably confused by is that some PCB houses also offer assembly services.  Those could be turnkey or not.  But that's really a assembly issue.  Someone doing turnkey assembly for you would get boards fabricated as part of the process.  The the same company is offering the turnkey assembly service that is also a PCB house, then they will produce the bare boards internally.  However, there are plenty of assembly houses that aren't also PCB fabs.  In that case for a turnkey job, they will subcontract out the PCB fab, usually to a company they have special business relationship with just for that purpose.

Comment: Fine answer.  I'll add that things that are not "turnkey" are either fully or partially "kitted", meaning that the customer provides all or some of the parts to the fabricator (i.e., the customer provides some "kit")

Answer (score 4):

They not only fab the PCB but also buy parts and do assembly.